# how to send a custom email using firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic3, angular2-template

I want to send an email to user when they redeem there coupon using firebase. I am using ionic 3 is it possible to do so. I had tried ionic native email-composer, but it was not that I want.

Comment: You can use cloud functions to achieve this.

There is an example on [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/Node-8/email-confirmation/functions/index.js) of how to trigger the function to send the email.

Comment: I have used this but the functions are not deploying